# Using a method a second time gives me an error (IOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im writing this app in objective c (Xcode).

when i use a method in the first time everything goes well, but when i use it the second time it gives me an error.

I tried to debug it and the error goes in the method add tutor in the line  if([tutor.userName isEqualToString:userName])

this is the error:

> -[__NSCFConstantString userName]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0xad14c 2016-02-26 20:10:44.043 project[1258:35474] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString
>   userName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xad14c'

this is my code:

```
- (IBAction)addToFavorite:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSString * userName = delegate.delegateStr;
    Student * student = [[Model instance]getStudentByUserName:userName];
    [student addTutor:self.tutor.userName];

    UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    FavoritesTableViewController * ftvc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"favoritesTableViewController"];
    ftvc.favTutors = student.favTutors;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"RefreshTable" object:nil userInfo:nil];

}



-(void)addTutor:(NSString*)userName {
    BOOL check = YES;
    for (Tutor * tutor in self.favTutors) {
        if([tutor.userName isEqualToString:userName])
            check = NO;
    }
    if(check)
        [self.favTutors addObject:userName];
}
```

Please help!!

Thanks.

Comment: The error message says that the `Tutor` instance is in truth an `NSString`, how is `favTutors` declared?

Comment: @property NSMutableArray * favTutors;

Comment: See the answers, you're adding `NSString` objects rather than `Tutor` objects to `favTutors`in the `addTutor` method. Declare `favTutors` as lightweight generic then the compiler will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's failing because you are adding `username` in your `favTutors` array instead of objects of `Tutor`. So when you add first object and then next time your enumerate through `self.favTutors` you actually have a string object which will not respond to `username` property.

Answer (score 2):

problem is here at the line i added comment. you are adding an `NSString` to objects full of `Tutor` objects. and in second call of this method, in for loop, tutor is actually an `NSString` and you are trying to call `tutor.userName` and it doesnt exist in `NSString` object.

```
-(void)addTutor:(NSString*)userName {
    BOOL check = YES;
    for (Tutor * tutor in self.favTutors) {
        if([tutor.userName isEqualToString:userName])
            check = NO;
    }
    if(check)
        [self.favTutors addObject:userName]; //problem here!!!!
}
```

My advice is to create tutor object and add it to your array.

```
-(void)addTutor:(NSString*)userName {
    BOOL check = YES;
    for (Tutor * tutor in self.favTutors) {
        if([tutor.userName isEqualToString:userName])
            check = NO;
    }
    if(check)
    {
        // create Tutor object and add it to array dont add NSString directly
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is in: if([tutor.userName isEqualToString:userName]) it works on the first time because the favTutors is empty so it dont go inside but in the second time the favTutors is not empty so when it go to the if it gives me an error

Comment: what i mean is the where first problem begins not where error raises